# Affine open for arbitrarily chosen 2 points on a scheme

Tags: general-topology, number-theory, algebraic-geometry, schemes, group-schemes

Let $X$ be a reduced scheme. If there are arbitrarily chosen two points $p_1, p_2 \in X$, does the following always hold?

### Q. There exists some affine open neighbourhood $U$ such that $U \ni p_1, p_2$.

I know this holds when ${\mathrm{dim}}. X = 1$, and when $p_i$ are generic points of divisors, or irreducible components, still holds.

However, I have difficulty to prove this when $p_i$ are maximal ideals, i.e., points.

Comment: Kleiman proved that a scheme over a field  is quasi-projective if and only if any finite set of points is contained in an affine open set.

Comment: For a specific counterexample, [Hironaka's example](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hironaka%27s_example#A_finite_subset_of_a_variety_need_not_be_contained_in_an_open_affine_subvariety) is useful.